# Conditional stylesheets from Chrome-IE compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code in my html:

```
<link href="~/App_Themes/Default/core.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link href="~/App_Themes/Default/ie.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

To my understanding, this says the following:

**To Chrome**
Load core.css to use on this file, the rest is a comment, so ignore that

**To IE**
Load core.css to use on this file... Oh wait, you're IE, so load ie.css instead

So far the ie stylesheet is overwriting the Chrome stylesheet in ie as it should, but the problem I'm having is that Chrome also reads ie.css which is ruining positioning of certain elements on the page

I've tried `<!-- if !IE]>...` and a few connotations of this and still have had no joy.

I've thought about just surrounding the elements in IE conditional comments with a different name, but that's a lot messier in the code.

All I need is to isolate the rules between the browsers (so that ie.css loads in Chrome/Firefox/etc and ie.css loads in IE)

Thanks, Ortund

Comment: A question: What is the advantage of using '~/' instead of './'?

Comment: I dunno... I develop in asp.NET and that uses ~/

Comment: I think you missanderstand that. The IE will load both css files and evaluates all definitions. The reason is, in css file 'ie.css' shall overwirte the previous definitions. You only can isolate rules to manage it that your target browsers ignore particular defined rules

Comment: So how do I get the page to say "if you're IE, use stylesheet A. If you're not IE, use stylesheet B instead"?

Comment: in Unix and Unix like systems `~` is the Home directory of the current user, probably in ASP.net they used the same idea.

Comment: by the way you should load always the same stylesheet and add some special rule in the `ie.css` to overwrite the basic stylesheet. Have two completly separated stylesheets is difficult to maintain.

Comment: @FezVrasta so how do I add a rule in the stylesheet to say "do this in IE, but do that in Chrome"?

Comment: Also, you're right about `~` ... It's used in asp.net (not classic) to target the website root

Comment: You must say "do this in all browsers" and "do this only in IE", I'm writing a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you missunderstand the conditional option. The IE7 will load both files and invoke the deinitions. For isolationg css style you have to mark the class names with special names.

Here an example:

Imagin there is a css rule:

```
.headless .content {background-color: yellow;}
```

All browser will understand this. If you want to change the background only for IE 7 you habe to define the rule as follow:

```
*:first-child+html .headless .content {background-color: red;}
```

How does it work:

*Chrome browser:*

`.headless .content` is a valid statement for me, so I will invoke it

```
:first-child+html .headless .content
```

is an invalid statement for me, so I will ignore it.

*IE7:*

`.headless .content`
 is a valid statement for me, so I will invoke it

`:first-child+html .headless .content` 
is also a valid statement for me, so I will invoke it either. And because the last statement does always win, I coulor the background red.

The keyword for it "*cross browser hacks*"

Comment: The more specific statement does always win, not the last.

Comment: That's true, but if you define the same rules more than one time, the last definition will win

Comment: I was a little confused about the `+html` part, so for anyone else, just copy this as is... Finally got it working, thanks reporter!

Answer (score 0):

**style.css**:

```
body {
   color: red;
}
```

**msie.css**:

```
body {
   color: blue;
}
```

index.html

```
[...]

<link href=/css/style.css rel=stylesheet>
<!--[if IE]><link href=/css/msie.css rel=stylesheet><![endif]-->

[...]

<body>I am red in all browsers but blue in MSIE</body>
```

You should follow this example and keep in mind about the [specifity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of the CSS statements.

Comment: basically, I'm just setting a 20px margin in all browsers except IE which is getting a margin: 0

Comment: Do you mean all browsers getting `margin:20px;` and IE gets `margin:0;` if that's the case than you have properties for the same element in both css files, so open ie.css find element and set `margin:20px;`

Comment: no... IE is supposed to get margin: 0; ... everything else should get margin: 20px;

Comment: so what's the problem? Write the right CSS rule in the two stylesheets. Remember that MSIE10 doesn't support conditional comments and will not be affected.

Comment: Did you try to find same element in ie.css and add `margin:0;`?

Comment: ... The problem is that the `margin-top: 0;` rule in `ie.css` is being used in Chrome as well whereas Chrome SHOULD be using `margin-top: -20px;` ... these are the **exact** rules I need

Comment: with my code Chrome will load only `style.css` and not `msie.css` so you have some problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: no change... I was wondering if I should swap it around so that core.css loads after the commented ie.css **EDIT** that didn't work either

Comment: I don't understand...I'm using `<!--[if lt IE...` for years now and never had a problem...do you have maybe some inline styles?